# Set foreign column to NULL when related row is deleted

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-2.x

I have users with two optional pictures (don't worry about the logic, the names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255),
    first_picture_id INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    second_picture_id INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_users_second_picture_id FOREIGN KEY (second_picture_id) REFERENCES pictures (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_users_first_picture_id FOREIGN KEY (first_picture_id) REFERENCES pictures (id)
);

CREATE TABLE pictures (
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I've linked my models this way (I hope that part's correct):

```
class User extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'FirstPicture' => array(
            'className' => 'Picture',
            'foreignKey' => 'first_picture_id',
        ),
        'SecondPicture' => array(
            'className' => 'Picture',
            'foreignKey' => 'second_picture_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

```
class Picture extends AppModel{
    public $hasOne = array(
        'User',
    );
}
```

Now, when I remove either picture:

```
$this->FirstPicture->delete($this->request->data('FirstPicture.id'));
```

...  I want to set the corresponding column in `user` set to `NULL`.

What'd be the CakePHP idiom (if any) to replicate an `ON DELETE SET NULL` foreign key deletion?

Comment: You'd have to do that manually, there is no such functionality in CakePHP 2.x associations (in 3.x it's currently only for `hasMany` associations IIRC). Is there a specific reason why you don't want to let the database handle that?

Comment: @ndm CakePHP schema and migrations do not support foreign keys at all and my predecesors addressed it with a quick and dirty hack that adds partial support—meaning that `schema create` works, everything else doesn't, and foreign keys necessarily use the default action (`ON DELETE RESTRICT`). To do what you suggest I'd need to either hack the hack or make database changes manually, and in both cases expect everybody else to always apply my changes (something unlikely to happen). Since everything else is already handled at application layer, it's easier to just do this the same way.

Comment: Plus, it's always good to have answers to "how to" questions. Even a "you cannot" kind of answer can save you time.

Comment: Implementing support for constraints isn't too complicated, I've done that in the past. I'll see if I can find it somewhere in the backups... Other than that, there isn't much you can do besides doing it "manually" in for example `beforeDelete/afterDelete`.

Comment: @ndm If you have the inclination to compose an answer I'll gladly accept it. Having the key info that it isn't a builtin feature and reminding about the `beforeDelete` hook is pretty useful even without actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality built into CakePHP 2.x that would automatically do that, you'd have to implement that on your own. Whenever possible it would be advised to use actual foreign key constraints in your database, but if that's not possible, then you don't really have much options here.

It should be easy enough doing that in the `beforeDelete` or `afterDelete` events/callbacks. If your database supports transactions (and your app uses them - they don't happen automatically for delete operations), then `beforeDelete` is advised as it can easily stop the deletion process. Without transactions, it would depend on what you like better in an error scenario, nulled foreign keys without the associated records being deleted (`beforeDelete`), or deleted associated records with non-nulled foreign keys (`afterDelete`).

Here's a simple example, you could do it from either side of the association, `Picture`:

```php
public function beforeDelete($cascade = true) {
    if (!parent::beforeDelete($cascade)) {
        return false;
    }

    $result = $this->User->updateAll(
        array('first_picture_id' => null),
        array('first_picture_id' => $this->getID())
    );
    if (!$result) {
        return false;
    }

    $result = $this->User->updateAll(
        array('second_picture_id' => null),
        array('second_picture_id' => $this->getID())
    );
    if (!$result) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

or `User`:

```php
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
{
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    $this->FirstPicture->getEventManager()->attach(
        function () {
            return $this->updateAll(
                array('first_picture_id' => null),
                array('first_picture_id' => $this->FirstPicture->getID())
            );
        },
        'Model.beforeDelete'
    );

    $this->SecondPicture->getEventManager()->attach(
        function () {
            return $this->updateAll(
                array('second_picture_id' => null),
                array('second_picture_id' => $this->SecondPicture->getID())
            );
        },
        'Model.beforeDelete'
    );
}
```